# Problema com instalação do SAP NETWEAVER no Linux

Tags: linux, erp, abap, vmware, opensuse

Estou tento problemas com a instalação do SAP Netweaver SP02.750, estou instalando no Linux openSUSE 15.0 numa VM. Após os comando para instalação:

```
sudo ./intall.sh
```

ele acusa o seguinte erro:

> "The hostname you have chosen is either configured on a loopback
>   device or not active on this server, please check your configuration
>   and hostname selection. If you are confident about your choice of
>   hostname, start the install script with -s flag to skip the hostname
>   check."

Alguém já passou por esse problema que tenha resolvido?

Comment: Sabe dizer a importância do hostname no processo de instalação? Caso não tenha relevância, você pode fazer como sugere a mensagem, fazer a instalação com `./install.sh -s` para evitar a validaçãodo hostname. Outra opção é verificar o hotname da sua máquina e alterar ele para algo que indique que se trata da sua máquina.

Comment: Cara até onde eu conheço sap e trabalho com isso, e que ele não funciona em outros sistemas operacionais. por exemplo muitas aplicações são feitas para o internet explorer.